# How to implement Tensorflow batch normalization in LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My current LSTM network looks like this.

```py
rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=CELL_SIZE)
init_s = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size=1, dtype=tf.float32)  # very first hidden state
outputs, final_s = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    rnn_cell,              # cell you have chosen
    tf_x,                  # input
    initial_state=init_s,  # the initial hidden state
    time_major=False,      # False: (batch, time step, input); True: (time step, batch, input)
)

# reshape 3D output to 2D for fully connected layer
outs2D = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, CELL_SIZE])
net_outs2D = tf.layers.dense(outs2D, INPUT_SIZE)

# reshape back to 3D
outs = tf.reshape(net_outs2D, [-1, TIME_STEP, INPUT_SIZE])
```

Usually, I apply [`tf.layers.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) as batch normalization. But I am not sure if this works in a LSTM network.

```py
b1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(outputs, momentum=0.4, training=True)
d1 = tf.layers.dropout(b1, rate=0.4, training=True)

# reshape 3D output to 2D for fully connected layer
outs2D = tf.reshape(d1, [-1, CELL_SIZE])                       
net_outs2D = tf.layers.dense(outs2D, INPUT_SIZE)

# reshape back to 3D
outs = tf.reshape(net_outs2D, [-1, TIME_STEP, INPUT_SIZE])
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1736

Comment: Following the link above there has been an implementation of bn for lstm that isn’t pulled into master yet.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/14106/commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use batch norm for RNN (LSTM or GRU), you can check out [this implementation](https://github.com/OlavHN/bnlstm/blob/master/lstm.py) , or read the full description from [blog post](http://olavnymoen.com/2016/07/07/rnn-batch-normalization).

However, the layer-normalization has more advantage than batch norm in sequence data. Specifically, "the effect of batch normalization is dependent on the mini-batch size and it is not obvious how to apply it to recurrent networks" (from the paper [Ba, et al. Layer normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450)).

For layer normalization, it normalizes the summed inputs within each layer. You can check out the [implementation](https://gist.github.com/danijar/ff8b4b81da55c99b5096913c4953d29b) of layer-normalization for GRU cell:

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450): *"Layer Normalization" - Jimmy Lei Ba, Jamie Ryan Kiros, Geoffrey E. Hinton*

Tensorflow now comes with the [`tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py) a LSTM unit with layer normalization and recurrent dropout.

Find the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LayerNormBasicLSTMCell).